# JavaScript breakpoints no longer working in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, breakpoints

My Visual Studio JavaScript breakpoints are no longer working. They don't now.  I have tried *everything* that I could find on the web.  the javascript statement debugger dosn't work in FF either (and no, it's not on the first line of the function) debugger does work in IE but I need debug for FF issues. Firebug, IMHO sucks - just look at that watch list you have to wade through. I need the immediate window to check vars ect.  I have tried in the latest FF, Chrome and IE. But VS2008 just won't break anywhere in Javascript.

Debugging is enabled everywhere on everything, I have tried attaching to the browsers, deleting temp files, clearing caches, ect, ect, ect, ect, ect. Tried every thing short of a 12 gauge shotgun (I'm saving my shells for the next microsoft employee I come across).  The last thing I tried is a repair of VS. Nope, didn't work. I tried a complete VS uninstall, regclean, defrag while I was at it and then a reinstall of VS2008 and SP1. After the reinstall I tried a blank page with 1 button and one 3 line function shown below.

```
function TestIt() {
  var x = 0;
  debugger;
  alert("In Test function");
}
```

put the breakpoint on the `var x = 0;` line. Nope, didn't work.

Microsoft doesn't have any answers, they act like it's the first that they have heard of it.  Seems that this issue has been around since vs2003 and people still have this problem in vs2010. Ideas?

Comment: When you set a breakpoint with the mouse, does it say a message like "this breakpoint will never be hit?"

Comment: "statement debugger doesn't work in FF either" --- how so? Did you try using FireBug?

Comment: Mic - It did before the reinstall of VS now the breakpoint icon normal

Comment: InfinitiesLoop I can break in firebug by using a firebug breakpoint.  But I want it to break in VS2008 like it used to.  the javascript 'debugger' statement will work in IE but I am trying to resolve FireFox issues and am not adept at firebug there is not an immediate window where I can paste statements to evaluate them ie. I can't go ?document.getelementbyid('blah').value or view the contents of an object.  Oh, firebug has lists of all kinds of stuff, just not what I want or am remotely interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I got tired of iffy javascript debuggers and have been heavily using logging instead.

Comment: That is an option I haven't considered.  If I can just get VS2008 breakpoints to work in JS functions like they did before I would be golden.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Chrome's debugger? I've long since abandoned Firebug in favor of Chrome.

Comment: My page works great in IE. Now I am trying to make it work in FF. Chrome will be next.  Thanks for the suggestion I'll give it a try now. Maybe I can work the cross browser issues in chrome.